# function return double array contain three value

Tags: c#, arrays, html, return

write a function that returns a `double` array. That array contains three values: `three number inputs via the user,

ASPX code:

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false"
```

%>

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head runat="server">
        <title>D</title>
    </head>
    <body>



                                                 <br/>               
            <asp:Button id="t" runat="server" Text="o"  /> 
                <br/> <br/>   
                 Result:<asp:TextBox id="cc"  runat="server"  /> 
                        <asp:TextBox id="zz" runat="server" /> 
                        <asp:TextBox id="yy"  runat="server"  />
        </form>

    </body>
    </html>



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: which line is causing you trouble? what exception do you get?

Comment: Use the debugger and step through your code. You can hover variables while debugging and e.g. VS will show the current containing value, so you can monitor where some unexpected behaviour is going on.

Comment: @R.S So you think we can randomly guess correct what line 684 is? This is just nonsense.

Comment: Try returning void on your function and see what happens? The delegate for asp:Button does not return a value.

Answer (score 1):

"Math" is an event handler method, try to declare it as void:

```
    public void MathOps(object sender, EventArgs args)
```

you are already setting your textbox properly inside the method, i don't think you need an additional array as return, at least this wouldn't be the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldnt be returning a value for a asp:Button element delegate method. Try changing the return value to void instead of string[].

**UPDATE**

Since you said you want to keep your MathOps function returning data, and I assume keep your delegate method also...you should try something like this:

Youll need to do something like this:

```
public void CalculateHandler(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
        var returnedValuesArr = MathOps();
        Avg.Text = returnedValuesArr[0];
}
```

I would NOT reference the asp:Textbox element(or any other UI elements) from inside of the MathOps function. Do that from inside your handler.

Obviously, if you change the delegate handler name in your code, youll also need to update that on your UI Button element. So, youd need to change:

```
 <asp:Button id="Cal" runat="server" Text="Calculate" OnClick="MathOps" />
```

to

```
 <asp:Button id="Cal" runat="server" Text="Calculate" OnClick="CalculateHandler" />
```

By the way...youd also probably want to send in the values(Num1.Text, Num2.Text, etc) for your MathOps method as parameters.

Comment: The codes work by void method, but i want to return the three value on array ,Where should I put MathOps in the aspx ?